# How can I have apexchart display different values for title of tooltip and xaxis?

Tags: apexcharts

Please take a look at [this code](https://codepen.io/zolash/pen/bxJogV) for example.

So when you hover the chart the popup tooltip includes the name of the month (just like what is written on `xaxis`) as it's title and then the data series.

In my case I have daily timestamps and data for each day. 
Now what I want is to display only the day number on the `xaxis` but the full date on the title of the popup tooltip.

How can I achieve this?